# Why is the acceleration on a charge in the electric field of a point charge constant?

Tags: electrostatics, coulombs-law

According to Coulomb's Law, 
$$F = k\frac{q_1q_2}{r^2}.$$ 
So as the distance decreases, $F$ should increase. Therefore $a = F/m$ should also increase right?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Why would you expect otherwise (as your title suggests)?

Comment: Thanks! The summary of my textbook's electrostatics lesson had the point that since electric field is constant, acceleration is also constant right after a point about point charges. I guess the point referred to the field between two parallel charged plates...

Comment: That will probably be the case. As you mentioned nothing about the point particle's field is constant.

Comment: @KarthikeyaKaza Since you have figured out the answer, I think you should post an answer to your own question.

Answer (score 2):

The acceleration for a point charge is not constant. It varies with position and so do the electric field and force on the particle. The acceleration is constant only for an infinite parallel plate capacitor.

Answer (score 1):

The law you mentioned is only valid for point charges.When a charge is in an electric field then the force acting on it is given as $$\vec{F}=q\vec{E}$$ The force depends upon the nature of electric field as it may vary with time and space or it may be constant.